# Is it better to spawn a new thread or create a new process in multi core system?

Tags: linux, multithreading, asynchronous, multiprocessing

I have Linux system with 2 cores and I am running an application that is single threaded and most of the times it has to wait for I/O operations so I have made it asynchronous. When I load test the application most of the time only one CPU will be at 100% but the other CPU will be with almost no load.

**My question:**

1. If I want to have a load on the other CPU which will not be utilized is it better to create a new process or spawn multiple threads and let the thread/process handle the load?
2. If I spawn a different thread will it be using the same CPU on which it was created or the OS will select the CPU that is ideal?
3. How many threads can I create without degradation in the performance?
4. How many processes can I create without degradation in the performance?
5. What if I create 2 processes and spawn threads from those two processes?

Comment: It really depends. There is no universal answer. As a rule of thumb, avoid having lots of threads or processes (so at most a dozen, and probably less, in your case). A thread is usually not tied to a physical core, but read about [processor affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity)

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: The article that you have provided is really helpful. I have 2vCPUs so is it better if I run it in threaded environment ?

Comment: Again, there is no single answer. Your question is *too broad*. You need to **benchmark** to find the optimal in your particular case. Read also some [POSIX thread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). Also 2vCPUs does not means much (it is a marketing buzzword, without defined technical reality)

Comment: The most easiest solution that may or may not fit your requirements is to run the synchronous process twice ...

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia I don't think running them synchronously will suite my requirement. Because I have a lot of I/O and running them synchronously will definitely increase the time.